# How to cast nullable type of a parameter on a linq2sql join statement

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, casting, nullable

somehow I cant figure out how to cast the type of linq paramter within the ON-part of the statement. the statement will lead to the following error:

> Error 1   The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'.

The type of ProjectID = pID is int, as well as r.ProjectID. So does  anyone have a clue what causes this error?

```
ViewData.Model = (from c in _db.Category
    join r in _db.CategoryAndProject2
    on new { c.CategoryID, ProjectID = pID } equals new { r.CategoryID,  r.ProjectID }
    into join1
    from j in join1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new CategoryDTO
    {
    CatID = (int) j.CategoryID    
    }).Distinct().ToList();
```

**edited** the ON-line, because of missing code

Comment: Try casting to a nullable int. IE: `on new { CategoryID = (int?)c.CategoryID...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
on (int?)c.CategoryID equals r.CategoryID
```

There is no need for anonymous types in the join.

Comment: actually I compare two parameters:
`on new { c.CategoryID, ProjectID = pID } equals new { r.CategoryID,  r.ProjectID }`

Comment: Maybe the problem is with `pID` and `ProjectID`? Because the cast to `int?` should be just fine.

Comment: when I delete ProjectID = ID and the equivalent r.ProjectID I don't receive any error. So it must be the first pair

Comment: If you delete `ProjectID` and no longer get an error, `ProjectID` is the problem.

Comment: ah, sorry. it's the other way around: If i delete c.CategoryID/r.CategoryID, I dont get an error

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
from c in _db.Category
join r in _db.CategoryAndProject2
on new { c.CategoryID, ProjectID = pID } equals
   new { CategoryID = r.CategoryID ?? 0,  r.ProjectID }
...
```

It may be more efficient though to do

```
from c in _db.Category
join r in _db.CategoryAndProject2
on new { CategoryID = (int?)c.CategoryID, ProjectID = pID } equals
   new { r.CategoryID, r.ProjectID }
...
```

because this translates into a straight join on the fields without conversion. The first query contains a `COALESCE`, which rules out the use of an index.